# Create Function to a RasterStack

Tags: raster, r, remote-sensing, function

This is the function that I want to create:

*Erosivity_Factor = 1.74 * log[sum(montly²/annual)]+1.29*

I have solved it using a loop:

```
# Reproducible RasterStack with 12 layers
Monlty<- stack(lapply(1:12, function(i) raster(ncol=20, nrow=20, vals=rnorm(400,30)))) 

# Reproducible Raster
Annual <- raster(ncol=20, nrow=20, vals=rnorm(400,230))

R_month<- list()

for (i in 1:12) {
  R_month[[i]]<- (Monlty[[i]]*Monlty[[i]]/Annual)
          }

R_month_raster <- do.call(stack,R_month)
R_erosivity_factor<- (1.74*log10(calc(R_month_raster,sum))+1.29)
```

Is there a way to make it with a function?

Answer (score 2):

First, a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)

r <- raster()

l <- list()

for(i in 1:12){
  l[[i]] <- setValues(r,rep(i,ncell(r)))
}

s <- stack(l)
```

You need to create your function and then apply it with `calc` function. Is annual the sum of all month values? or is annual an average? Well, I considered the sum of all monthly values, you can change it later:

```
Erosivity_Factor <- function(x){1.74*log10((x^2)/sum(x))+1.29}

R_erosivity_factor <- calc(s,Erosivity_Factor)
```

Since the value of the raster increases every month, results have sense:ç

```
plot(R_erosivity_factor,zlim=c(-2.1,1.8))
```

[image]

---

For only two raster objects the approach is direct:

```
R_erosivity_factor <- 1.74*log10((Monlty^2)/Annual)+1.29
```

Comment: It is a good approach, neverless I need to compute the function with two Raster objects, since Annual != sum of the monthly values, and calc() admits only one Raster object.

Comment: I have fixed it but it takes three times longer than the loop. I had thought that a function would speed up the process:

    x <- stack(Monlty,Annual)

    Erosivity_Factor <- function(x){1.74*log10(sum(x[c(1:12)]^2/(x[c(13)])))+1.29}

    R_erosivity_factor <- calc(x,Erosivity_Factor)

Comment: @franciscocorvalan I added an approach with two rasters objects. Although I don't really understand the composition of both rasters. Is monthly raster a 12-band raster while annual is 1-band?